# AWS EC2: Migrating from Windows to Linux Server

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I am currently using Amazon Web Services EC2 Windows 2012 instance for my application. I want to migrate over to an EC2 Linux server. What's the best way do this? I have been unable to find sufficient resources on this topic. We are currently using Hibernate and Spring frameworks with MySQL and Apache Tomcat servers.

Comment: why would someone down-vote this without reasonable cause? it's a valid question and the one answer did help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is realizing the main problem is not the server software and operating system but your application. You need to be sure that your application runs on Linux and you don't have any Windows dependent libraries.

Then you can create a Linux EC2 instance (Ubuntu, RedHat or any other distribution). Roughly the steps could be these:

- Create the EC2 instance.
- Install Apache Tomcat, MySQL Server.
- Decide if Hibernate, Spring and any other libraries will be bundled with your application or system wide.
- Deploy your application in the EC2 Linux instance.
- Debug and fix the problems that surface.